# Вопрос laravel 10 не работает redirect при использовании middleware?

Tags: php, laravel

Добрый день подскажите пожалуйста, выдает ошибку при redirect с использованием middleware.
Ошибка: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS Сайт localhost выполнил переадресацию слишком много раз.
Что поправить надо??

Код midlleware

```
  public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        if(auth()->user()->role !== 'admin') {
            return redirect()->route('home');
       }  
        return $next($request);   
    }
```

Код роутов web.php

```
Route::get('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index');

Route::get('/my_page', 'App\Http\Controllers\MyFirstController@index');

Route::get('/about', 'App\Http\Controllers\MyAboutController@index')->name('about.index');
Route::get('/contacts', 'App\Http\Controllers\MyContactsController@index')->name('contact.index');
Route::get('/main', 'App\Http\Controllers\MyMainController@index')->name('main.index');

Route::group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Post'], function () {
    Route::get('/posts', 'IndexController')->name('post.index');
    Route::get('/posts/create', 'CreateController')->name('post.create');
    Route::get('/posts/{post}', 'ShowController')->name('post.show');
    Route::post('/posts/create', 'StoreController')->name('post.store');
    Route::get('/posts/{post}/edit', 'EditController')->name('post.edit');
    Route::patch('/posts/{post}', 'UpdateController')->name('post.update');
    Route::delete('/posts/{post}', 'DestroyController')->name('post.delete');
});

Route::group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin', 'prefix' =>'admin', 'middleware'=>'admin'], function () {

    Route::group(['namespace' => 'Post'], function () {
        Route::get('post', 'IndexController')->name('admin.post.index');
    });
});

require __DIR__.'/auth.php';

\Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
```

Comment: Проверять авторизацию надо на всех роутах, кроме `home`. Иначе без авторизации тебя пинает на home, а там опять проверяется авторизация и пинает на home и так __бесконечно__

Comment: Тогда вопрос как их проверить?))

Comment: Что проверить? `app/Http/Kernel.php` в этом файле в переменной $middleware список всех middleware которые к каждому запросу применяются, значит она где-то там. Чтобы убрать её у роута можно добавить `->withoutMiddleware('auth')`, auth - алиас, для примера.. если нет алиаса то класс туда прописать

Comment: В зависимости от того как тебе удобно, логично добавить мидлвару либо на каждый отдельный роут или же на сам контроллер. Например для каждого контроллера добавить в `__construct()`такой вызов `$this->middlware('auth');` А если нужно исключить какой-то метод из него. то добавить `->except(['index']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем я не правильно зарегистрировал middleware в файле Kernel.php. Спасибо всем большое, что навели на путь истиный. Выкладываю правильный код.

```
 protected $middlewareAliases = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'auth.session' => \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \App\Http\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminPanelMiddleware::class
    ];
```